# React: mount/unmount animation of component with variable height

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I am trying to animate a component with variable height (different inner content to display). I tried to use `react-motion`, but the non-knowledge of height beforehand messed me up.

What I tried to do, was rendering the element wrapped in an `overflow hidden; height 0, transition height .25s` div, measure it's height, then set the wrapper's height to the element's height. it worked, but was laggy

I wanted to do this the React way, but failed to find a solution when the element height is not needed beforehand.

One solution would be rendering it - somewhere -, measure it's height and then apply it in the `react-motion` animation. This, however, does an extra render - i opt to not use this solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-collapse` is the answer for this very problem.